# Como hago para que varios usuarios entren al tiempo en mi programa .net?

Tags: .net

Como le hago para que una aplicación desktop en .net con una base de datos sql server funcione en varios pc's. Me refiero a que varios usuarios puedan utilizarlo al tiempo.

Comment: No tienes que hacer nada, siempre y cuando en tu aplicación gestiones correctamente los accesos a la base de datos. Tienes algun problema en concreto? Porque esta pregunta tal como está tiene una respuesta: nada.

Comment: Funciona bien en un solo equipo, lo ensayare.